# masking and input value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a task that consists in masking the value that the user puts in an input.

So far I have got to validate the number but can not mask it.

What I need is that a number, for example

`13589294579294` changes to `########9294`.

I have done the functions and they work as you can see I am importing those functions.

The thing is that every time I use the function **`validator.maskify()`**

the console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "innerHTML" on "324543": not an object

#### My Code:

Javascript:

```js
let numero = document.getElementById('numeroTarjeta').value
numero.innerHTML = validator.maskify(numero)
if (validator.isValid(numero) === true) {
    let tarjeta_valida = document.createElement('div')
    tarjeta_valida.setAttribute('div', 'tarjetaValida')
    let div_tarjeta = document.querySelector('.tarjeta')
    div_tarjeta.appendChild(tarjeta_valida)
} else {
    let tarjeta_invalida = document.createElement('div')
    tarjeta_invalida.setAttribute('div', 'tarjetaInvalida')
    let div_tarjeta = document.querySelector('.tarjeta')
    div_tarjeta.appendChild(tarjeta_invalida)
    
}

console.log(numero)

console.log(validator);
```

HTML:

```html
<section>
      <div class="tarjeta">
        <h4 class="tu-tarjeta">TU TARJETA DE CRÉDITO</h4>
        <span class="compras">COMPRAS</span>
        <br>
        <label for="nuemeroTarjeta">número de tarjeta:</label> <br>
        <input id="numeroTarjeta" type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu numero de tarjeta">
        <button>validar</button>
        <br>
        <span>VENCIMIENTO MM/YY</span>
      </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your js script try this

```js
import validator from './validator.js';
//accediendo al input text
let numeroDom = document.getElementById('numeroTarjeta')
let numero = numeroDom.value
numeroDom.innerHTML = validator.maskify(numero)
if (validator.isValid(numero) === true) {
    let tarjeta_valida = document.createElement('div')
    tarjeta_valida.setAttribute('div', 'tarjetaValida')
    let div_tarjeta = document.querySelector('.tarjeta')
    div_tarjeta.appendChild(tarjeta_valida)
} else {
    let tarjeta_invalida = document.createElement('div')
    tarjeta_invalida.setAttribute('div', 'tarjetaInvalida')
    let div_tarjeta = document.querySelector('.tarjeta')
    div_tarjeta.appendChild(tarjeta_invalida)
    
}


console.log(numero)

console.log(validator);
```

Explainin:
getElementById render a dom object which is the html object which you can use with (innerHTML and other features) so you were getting in numero the value of dom, then you want to use with this value (int) the innerHTML so what we did is to get the dom then retreive its value so we put in the dom's html the maskify of its value

i hope this was helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

in the `numero` variable, you are getting the `value`

> `value` is the string you get from the input

---

> `value` isn't the input itself on the DOM

so you need to also add another variable with the DOM element

```js
const numberoEl = document.getElementById('numeroTarjeta'); // <input>
const numero = numeroEl.value;                              // 13589294579294
```

---

also in the input don't use `type="text"`,

but use **[`type="tel"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)** or use **[`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)**

which is good because gives the user a good keyboard,

and saves you from a lot of checking

because with input number we can't insert a letter

and so in javascript, you don't have to check if all numbers match a certain regex.

---

so with this code, when focusing you will have this correct keyboard automatically.

```html
<input 
  id="numeroTarjeta" 
  type="number" 
  placeholder="Introduce tu numero de tarjeta"
>
```

[image]